# generating pi to nth digit java

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal, pi

I wanted to know how I can generate pi to the nth digit. I have a couple of basic ideas.

1. Use `Math.PI` and increase the precision (if that's possible)
2. Use Euler's formula to generate pi but even here, I would need to increase the precision (I think)
   [image: Euler's formula for PI]
3. There is also Srinivasa Ramanujan's formula for generating PI which is known for it's rapid convergence. This formula seems difficult to implement. I believe, I would have to also increase deicmal precision here.
   [image]

So in short, either way, I would need to increase the precision of `BigDecimal` depending on what the nth digit is. How would I go about increasing the precision of `BigDecimal` to nth digit? Also, if there is a better and faster of doing this, can you please point me in the correct direction.

EDIT: I just want to generate PI. I don't want to use for calculations. and this is a question about how I can use BigDecimal to implement my ideas of generating PI.

Comment: Do you actually need to generate Pi or do you need it for calculations?

Comment: Is this a question about the maths behind computing pi, or about how to use `BigDecimal`?

Comment: I'm just using BigDecimal to implement the PI formulae and I don't need PI to calculate, I just want to generate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `Math.PI` is of type `double`. That means about 15 decimal digits of precision, and that is all the data you have; nothing will magically make additional digits of PI appear.
- `BigDecimal` has arbitrary precision. `setScale()` allows you to create `BigDecimal` objects with as much precision as you want and most of the arithmetic methods will automatically increase precision as required, but of course the more precision, the slower all calculations will be.
- The most difficult part of implementing Ramanujan's formula will ironically be the sqrt(2) in the constant factor, because there is not built-in sqrt() for `BigDecimal`, so you'll have to write your own.

Comment: But for the square root, the good old Heron method converges fast enough even with a million (or a billion) digits of precision.

Comment: for the sqrt(2) part, can I not just use the pre-defined value? 1.41421356, or will that change the calculation somehow?

Comment: @user681159: well, as soon as you want your value of PI to be more precise that that "pre-defined value", you'll need more digits of sqrt(2).

Comment: @user681159: Isn't it pretty obvious that if you want to calculate a very precise result based in a specific constant factor, you can't do that with an imprecise approximation of that factor?

Comment: sorry, I missed that. Cut me some slack.

Comment: For your last point, about the square root of 2 being the hardest  would you not be able to do `BigDecimal sr2 = new BigDecimal(new BigDecimal(2).pow(1/2), MathContext(1000));`, replacing 1000 with your desired precision?  EDIT: Nevermind, the first argument is an int, not allowing for use of rational exponents.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `MathContext` to increase the precision of the `BigDecimal`

e.g.

```
MathContext mc = new MathContext(1000);
BigDecimal TWO = new BigDecimal(2, mc);
```

It's important that ALL the `BigDecimal`s you use in your calculations use that `MathContext`.
Heron's method should give you 1000 digits precision with only 10 iterations and a million digits with 20 iterations so it's certainly good enough.
Also, create all the constant `BigDecimal`s like e.g. `26390` only once at the start of your program.

Comment: What do you mean by Heron's method?

Comment: @user681159 Heron's method coincides with the Newton-Raphson method for the case of square roots, in case you are familiar with the latter. Otherwise: it's finding better approximations to `sqrt(a)` via `x_(n+1) = 1/2*(x_n + a/x_n)`. It converges for all `a > 0` and any starting value `x_0 > 0`. If you start with a fairly good approximation, in each step the number of correct digits doubles (approximately).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public final class Pi {

private static final BigDecimal TWO = new BigDecimal("2");
private static final BigDecimal FOUR = new BigDecimal("4");
private static final BigDecimal FIVE = new BigDecimal("5");
private static final BigDecimal TWO_THIRTY_NINE = new BigDecimal("239");

private Pi() {}

public static BigDecimal pi(int numDigits) {

  int calcDigits = numDigits + 10;

  return FOUR.multiply((FOUR.multiply(arccot(FIVE, calcDigits)))
    .subtract(arccot(TWO_THIRTY_NINE, calcDigits)))
    .setScale(numDigits, RoundingMode.DOWN);
}

 private static BigDecimal arccot(BigDecimal x, int numDigits) {

BigDecimal unity = BigDecimal.ONE.setScale(numDigits,
  RoundingMode.DOWN);
BigDecimal sum = unity.divide(x, RoundingMode.DOWN);
BigDecimal xpower = new BigDecimal(sum.toString());
BigDecimal term = null;

boolean add = false;

for (BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal("3"); term == null ||
  term.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0; n = n.add(TWO)) {

  xpower = xpower.divide(x.pow(2), RoundingMode.DOWN);
  term = xpower.divide(n, RoundingMode.DOWN);
  sum = add ? sum.add(term) : sum.subtract(term);
  add = ! add;
}
return sum;
}
}
```

[resource](http://en.literateprograms.org/Pi_with_Machin%27s_formula_%28Java%29)

Comment: There is a problem with this code it leads to an infinite loop under certain conditions ;-(