# Obtaining nth digit of BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal, pi

Is there any way to get a nth digit from BigDecimal?

Using this article --> [generating pi to nth digit java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370290/generating-pi-to-nth-digit-java)

I set up a value of pi using Euler's formula in a BigDecimal.  Now I would like to be able to call on a particular digit of it.

```
int getPiDigit(3) = 4    // 3.14
```

I was thinking maybe there would be a way that I could take the BigDecimal and store it's values in an array somehow.  I originally tried getting the value as a String, but when it is converted to a string it only takes about 47 characters.  For my use, I need to at least go to 512.

Here is some sample code to show what i'm doing...

```
MathContext mc = new MathContext(1000);
BigDecimal pi = new BigDecimal(20*Math.atan(1.0/7) + 8*Math.atan(3.0/79) ,mc); //Should give pi up to 1000 digits
System.out.println(pi.toString().charAt(50)); 
//Throws Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 50
```

Comment: Just turn the BD into a string and get the nth character. I have no idea what your last two sentences mean. You must have done something wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're computing *pi* as a double and then converting it to BigDecimal. That won't magically add more precision than was in the double, which by definition can't be more than 53 bits.

You need to do the computation of pi *in BigDecimal.*

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to convert the `BigDecimal` to a `String`, and you can simply make use of `String#charAt(int)`

I am not sure why you can't get hold of 47 characters.  The String conversion should convert all digits up to the scale you defined in your BigDecimal.  The problem most probably is caused by incorrect use of BigDecimal in you Pi calculation logic

---

Your assumption seems invalid: passing in MathContext with `BigDecimal(double, MathContext)` does not necessary make the result containing the significant figures declared by MathContext.  Quoted from Javadoc:

> Translates a double into a BigDecimal, with rounding according to the context settings. The scale of the BigDecimal is the smallest value such that (10^scale × val) is an integer.

The way you do is also irrational: for `double`, it is only accurate for 15 significant figure.  Taking 1000 significant figure from your double calculation result doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call setScale() to set the number of decimal places you want before calling toString(), like this:

```
pi.setScale(n, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
```

'n' is the number of decimal places. You want to round down, so that the nth decimal place is never rounded up.

Comment: I tried this (rounding to 512).  I noticed after the 50th character that the rest of the values were 0's.  Is this an error in the way that I calculated pi?  I tried printing just the BigDecimal itself (without conversion to String) and found that it also printed 0's after the 50th character.

Comment: I believe so. Floating point numbers have finite precision, so your technique will only work to a certain number of decimal places with precision. You should look at http://java.lykkenborg.no/2005/03/computing-pi-using-bigdecimal.html for one way to do this correctly.